# Python control flow with in keyword unexpected behaviour

Tags: python, control-flow

I am trying to print "YES" or "NO" (quotes for clarity) depending on whether any permutation of the pattern exists in the text string.

```
from itertools import permutations


i = int(input())

for j in range(i):
    m = input()
    n = input()

    lst = []
    for k in permutations(m):
        lst.append("".join(k))

    for l in lst:
        if l in n:
            print("YES")
            break
        else:
            print("NO")
            break

    print(lst)
```

This is the sample input:

```
3
hack
indiahacks
code
eddy
coder
iamredoc
```

This is the expected output

```
YES
NO
YES
```

For first two inputs, output is coming correctly and the third output is the one which fails.

```
/home/ajay/.pyenv/versions/3.4.1/bin/python3.4 /home/ajay/PycharmProjects/LearnPython/test.py
1
coder
iamredoc
NO
['coder', 'codre', 'coedr', 'coerd', 'corde', 'cored', 'cdoer', 'cdore', 'cdeor', 'cdero', 'cdroe', 'cdreo', 'ceodr', 'ceord', 'cedor', 'cedro', 'cerod', 'cerdo', 'crode', 'croed', 'crdoe', 'crdeo', 'creod', 'credo', 'ocder', 'ocdre', 'ocedr', 'ocerd', 'ocrde', 'ocred', 'odcer', 'odcre', 'odecr', 'oderc', 'odrce', 'odrec', 'oecdr', 'oecrd', 'oedcr', 'oedrc', 'oercd', 'oerdc', 'orcde', 'orced', 'ordce', 'ordec', 'orecd', 'oredc', 'dcoer', 'dcore', 'dceor', 'dcero', 'dcroe', 'dcreo', 'docer', 'docre', 'doecr', 'doerc', 'dorce', 'dorec', 'decor', 'decro', 'deocr', 'deorc', 'derco', 'deroc', 'drcoe', 'drceo', 'droce', 'droec', 'dreco', 'dreoc', 'ecodr', 'ecord', 'ecdor', 'ecdro', 'ecrod', 'ecrdo', 'eocdr', 'eocrd', 'eodcr', 'eodrc', 'eorcd', 'eordc', 'edcor', 'edcro', 'edocr', 'edorc', 'edrco', 'edroc', 'ercod', 'ercdo', 'erocd', 'erodc', 'erdco', 'erdoc', 'rcode', 'rcoed', 'rcdoe', 'rcdeo', 'rceod', 'rcedo', 'rocde', 'roced', 'rodce', 'rodec', 'roecd', 'roedc', 'rdcoe', 'rdceo', 'rdoce', 'rdoec', 'rdeco', 'rdeoc', 'recod', 'recdo', 'reocd', 'reodc', 'redco', 'redoc']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

You can see that `redoc` is present in the list of permutations but why the python `in` keyword is not recognizing it and thus producing `NO` output.

Comment: So if my answer helps, you'll add 2 points to your rep by accepting it. By the way, I did plus one this one for being interesting.

Answer (score 4):

You're breaking out of the loop over your list immediately after checking the first item in the list.

instead of:

```
for l in lst:
    if l in n:
        print("YES")
        break
    else...
```

If you must use a loop structure, you can rehabilitate your code with:

```
for l in lst:
    if l in n:
        print("YES")
        break
else: # this will run after (and only if) exhausting your loop.
    print("NO")
```

Raymond Hettinger thought this usage of `else` should be called `nobreak` and I think that's good intuition for it.

---

This is a [usage of the `else` clause on loops, and is documented here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops).

Comment: It works thanks :) Can you explain why this particular else out of the loop works. i m not getting it exactly.

Comment: It's control flow that only runs if the loop ends without breaking. That means you didn't find the substring, so you want `NO` printed there.

Comment: The time limit may exceed in this case. what if we want to do it within 2 sec.

Comment: Nothing in the question about a time limit, but if you want to guard against that, you'll have to build it into your control flow.